# Installing SSD on MacBook Pro Mid-2012 with Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd, data-transfer, hdd

So, I have a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro with 8GB RAM and 1TB HDD, with Bootcamp installed.

I want to replace the HDD with 500GB SSD Hard Drive, but I still have some doubts.

Even after surfing the internet for *hours* I couldn't get the answer to that- How do I transfer *all* my data, i.e. All my files, *without* reinstalling both MacOS and Bootcamp on the new SSD.

Meaning, I just want to transfer all data including both OS into the SSD so I don't have to reinstall both the OS

Comment: Can the answer include solutions that require purchasing third party products, such as [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) and [Winclone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/)?

Comment: The site rules don't allow it though

Comment: Third party products are frequently referred to. There is Windows, Office, Photoshop, Acrobat Reader, VirtualBox, Fusion Player, rEFInd, Ubuntu, FireFox, Chrome, Mint, Debian, Fedora, CentOS, etc. Why do you think the site rules don't allow this? Some are free, some are pay and some take donations. I was making an assumption that if you spent hours surfing without finding a solution, then you probably want a free solution. Otherwise, the products in my previous comment can be used to solve your problem.